# I have a question about the proofs disproving dividing zero in chapter 1, property 8, page 6, Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus

Spivak wrote that $0^{-1}$ is undefined because if $0^{-1}$ is defined, then $0^{-1}\cdot0 = 1$ but $0b = 0$ for any number, so this is false. 
What I don't understand is that in the previous properties/axioms, from P1 to P8, there is not one proposing that $0b = 0$ for any number, so how can he prove that without listing this property?

Comment: What in the world are axioms P1 to P8?

Comment: You can deduce $0b=0$ from the axioms, no doubt.  Think about the distributive law.

Comment: Hint: multiply $\,0+0 = 0\,$ by $\,b\,$ then cancel $\,0b\ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove $0b =0$.

And you can.

$0b $ exists as multiplication is binary op. $0b=(0+0)b=0b+0b $ by def of additive identity, substitution, and distribution.  $-0b $ exists by axiom.

So $0=0b+(-0b)=0b+0b+(-0b)=0b+0=0b $.

BTW.  When asking question don'don't assume people are familiar with your texts.  Your book refers to P1-P8 but no-one who isn't reading the book will actually know what you are talking about.